# htaccess redirect based on date

Tags: .htaccess

So this should be pretty simple, but it isn't working. I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{TIME_DAY} >12
RewriteRule /orderforms/page1.aspx.*$  https://www.site.net/orderforms/page2.aspx [R=301,QSA]
```

But even though it's not the 12th yet, it's still redirecting. Any ideas? Is this not fully supported? Thanks!

(I'm using ISAPI_Rewrite, though I don't think that should make any difference in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the pattern matching on `RewriteCond` is *lexiographic*, not *numerical*.

```
111 < 12
3523 < 34
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming format for %{TIME_DAY} is TWO digits and ranging from 01 to 31. Note that I don't know it's exact format, but this could still help you.

You could pull it off by using a *regular expression* on the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_DAY} ^[1-3][0-9]$
RewriteCond %{TIME_DAY} ^1[^012]$
```

Which accepts only a 1, 2 or a 3 in the first digit position and 0 ... 9 in the second digit position. You also need another RewriteCond to filter the unwanted 10, 11 and 12.